# pushing the button of cancel the value must return the initial value but it dosn't work

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, slider

```
$('#mdialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 320,
    buttons: {
        Apply: function() {
            <!--alert($('#slider').slider('option', 'value'));-->
            try{
                SendCommandToAO($('#slider').slider('option', 'value'), 'AO=a1c1p1', 0, 65535, 0, 65535, -1);
            } catch(e) {
                //Fool
            }
            //$(this).dialog("close"); 
        }, 
        Cancel: function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Need more information than just posting a bunch of code.  Especially what does the "value must return the initial value" mean? What value are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to reset the slider when you cancel.  In your cancel function, you can  set the value to whatever the default is, like this:

```
    Cancel: function() {
        $('#slider').slider('value', 50);
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
    }
```